# Trying to find a maximum from a file in shellscript

Tags: shell, sh

In shellscript, I'm trying to get the maximum value from different lines. There are 5 things in a line, and the fifth is the value, that I need to compare to the others in the lines. If I found, what the maximum is, then I have to write out the rest of the line too.

Any advices how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort numerically, by field 5, then print only the line containing the highest value:

```
sort -nk5,5 data.txt | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`< MYFILE sort  -k5nr | head -1`

`<` pipes MYFILE into `sort`,  `-k5` says to sort on the fifth key `n` is for numeric order, `r` sorts in reverse order so the largest number comes first.  Then `head -1` outputs only the first line. The end result is

`69.4206662, 12.3216747, 2021.08.21., 14:44, 20`

Comment: So let me get this clear, MYFILE stands for the .txt, that reads the lines, right? So if I have a data.txt, then it would be `data.txt < sort  -k5nr | head -1` , right? Cause if yes, then it doesn't work for me, cause the program doesn't find (?) the file. Also, I have to put the answer in the terminal, not into another new file.

Comment: MYFILE would be the .txt file that contains those lines. If this doesn't find `data.txt` what does `ls data.txt` say? If `ls` doesn't find the file, it isn't there... maybe you are in the wrong directory? Also this answer should put the answer in the terminal not a new file.

Comment: Both files are in the directory, and ls shows both of them.

Comment: @gmatht you have `MYFILE` and `sort` the wrong way around. You need `sort < MYFILE` (or `< MYFILE sort` if you really  want). Redirection isn't necessary anyway.